# Showing current/selected item in ListView in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `ListView` with about 400 entries. I need to search thru it for a value and when found I'm setting it to `Selected` and I would like `ListView` to somehow scroll to this item and show it on the screen.

How can I do this? Will setting .Focused do it?

```
        foreach (ListViewItem item in someListView.Items) {
            string varID = item.SubItems[0].Text;
            if (varID == someID) {
                item.Selected = true;
                item.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
                item.Focused = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `item.EnsureVisible();`